# $_SESSION variables showing unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session

I'm currently working on a table with `onclick()` `<td>` elements that send info to a PHP page.

The basic idea is that if a course is clicked (e.g.French, Maths, English, ...) the PHP page retrieves the value and afterwards executes the SQL code to give me all of the tutors for that specific course.

```
<script>
    function courseToTutor(id) {
        var courseClicked = document.getElementById("course" + id).value;
        $.post('loadDivs/loadTutors.php', {postname: courseClicked});
        $('#divTutors').load('loadDivs/loadTutors.php');
    }
</script>
```

When a `<td>` is clicked, it sends its id (generated in php) as a parameter. Inside the function I use that parameter to find the values within the `<td>` (stored inside an `input type="hidden"`).

I have a single PHP page that both gets the posted value, like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['postname'])) {
    $course = $_POST['postname'];
    $_SESSION['clickedCourse'] = $course;
    echo $course;
}
```

The other part of the page is

```
else {
  //generate table with tutors for a specific course (with SQL)
}
```

This works about 85% of the time. Yes, I use correct `session_start();`s, I have a proper database connection and so on.

When I click a `<td>`, I have an alert on the `loadTutors.php` that **always** triggers, it alerts my `$_SESSION['clickedCourse];`.

85% of the time this alert show the correct info, the other 15% of the time, it is empty.

It's not my other code on the page, because I trigger the alert before I execute that code.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
This is the php I use to generate the WHOLE table of courses.

```
<?php
$counter = 1;
if (!$res = $link->query($sqlSelectCourses)) {
    trigger_error('Error in query ' . $link->error);
} else {
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td onclick="courseToTutor(this.id);" id="<?php echo $counter; ?>">
                <?php echo $row["course"]; ?><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row["course"]; ?>" id="course<?php echo $counter; ?>">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $counter+=1;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you provide ajax body code?

Comment: Can you post your html ??

Comment: Is your session dying at the point where its trying to set the session variable? Could the 15% of the time not be where you havent made a significant call in more than 24 minutes?

Comment: Why are you sending an Ajax command and then loading the file? Why not just run `$.ajax().done()` ?

Comment: @IdealBakija Edited, hamed and Styphon, I don't know any ajax, I have no idea how to use it. JammyDodger231, I don't destroy my session, and this was tested by clicking in a timespan of less than 3 minutes.

Comment: Where is the `session_start()` in that 'whole' PHP?

Comment: At the top of the page, together with the include('dataConnection.php'); for my databaseconnection.

Comment: You could use the browsers network inspector to make sure it is not the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.post('loadDivs/loadTutors.php', {postname: courseClicked});
 $('#divTutors').load('loadDivs/loadTutors.php');
```

You are sending two requests, one to send data and one to receive new data. It **can** happen, that the second requests reaches the server first and i think this is what happens 15% the time (therefore wrong result). What you should do instead is using the first request and use its response:

```
 $.post('loadDivs/loadTutors.php', {postname: courseClicked}, function(response){
    $('#divTutors').html(response);
});
```

Edit: If you **can't** set your PHP-script up so it sends your new content directly at the "click-request", use this instead:

```
 $.post('loadDivs/loadTutors.php', {postname: courseClicked}, function(){
    $('#divTutors').load('loadDivs/loadTutors.php');
});
```

This will wait for the first request to finish before it starts the second.

Comment: Could just be the asynchronous call regardless of the order. But it seems to be the problem.

Comment: Your code replaces the "tutors" div with the clicked course, not with my other code on the php page. Would a `setInterval` work?

Comment: No, thats bad. Either rewrite your PHP-script so it sends your "new content" directly after updating or replace the line in my response-handler with your second ajax-call

Comment: Directly after updating what?

Comment: After updating whatever you are updating in your script in the first request (with POST-parameter "postname")

Comment: I tried rewriting the  code, but I don't think I fully understand what you mean.. I did a  `setTimeout` of 200 milliseconds and how it only happens when the user clicks very rapidly. It's bad practice, but meh

Comment: @Michiel you don't need to use the setTimeout but instead on success of the first ajax call.. call the second one. 
The best way to do it is to finish all your action in one php file like tkausl said.